# What are the ways of storing data coming from socket every seconds?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, socket.io, setinterval

I have socket connection in my backend (express.js) and data coming from that socket every seconds, I want to store these values to my database (postgresql). Since data is coming every seconds I do not want to store them when they come because it will be lots of writing operations. So I'm keeping them in `tempValues` and store the values to the database in every 1 min. But I feel like there has to be better way of doing this instead of using setInterval. Maybe a 3rd party library or something else? I'm okay to loose temporary data if server crashed or something happened.

Here is my current code block:

```
let tempValues = [];

setInterval(() => {
  tempValues.map(async (option, i) => {
    await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO plc_options (name, value, date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
      [option.name, option.value, option.timestamp]
    );
    if (i === tempValues.length - 1) tempValues = [];
  })

}, 60000);


socket.onAny((eventName, ...args) => {
  tempValues.push({ name: eventName, value: args[0], timestamp: new Date() })
});
```

Comment: Your solution (also known as buffering) is standard and fine. Except you probably need to swap the array with an empty one before update (to avoid races). As bonus you wont need if at the end. So what exactly you are looking for? Why change it?

Comment: I was not sure if this is a valid way of solving this kind of problem. Now I'm convinced, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a 3rd party library. Your idea is generally ok. It is known as buffering. I would improve it a bit though.

```
let _tempValues = [];

function getTempValues() {
    return _tempValues;
}

function getAndClearTempValues() {
    let oldTempValues = _tempValues;
    _tempValues = [];
    return oldTempValues;
}

setInterval(() => {
  let values = getAndClearTempValues();
  values.map(async (option, i) => {
    await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO plc_options (name, value, date) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)",
      [option.name, option.value, option.timestamp]
    );
  })

}, 60000);


socket.onAny((eventName, ...args) => {
  let values = getTempValues();   
  values.push({ name: eventName, value: args[0], timestamp: new Date() })
});
```

The major change is that I swap old `tempValues` with an empty array **before** looping through the array. That way we avoid a potential pitfal, when you asynchronously loop through the array, while the other code modifies it. As a bonus you don't need the if statement inside setInterval.